# Raising a user-defined event from a WPF control

Tags: wpf, xaml, events, custom-controls

I have a ListView control with support for incremental loading of large item collections. The loading of additional items is triggered when the user scrolls down to the bottom ListView's vertical scrollbar. I strive to use MVVM pattern in the implementation (no code-behind), but IMHO in this particular case it's not essential.

I am tinking about introducing a new event (e.g. NeedsMoreItems) and perhaps subclass ListView (ListViewWithIncrementalLoading) so the application won't need to do ScrollChanged events mapping. I haven't implemented custom events for XAML controls before, so I am not quite sure what's the easiest way to achive this. Do I need to create custom control? User control? Use attached events?

If you have code snippets from similar tasks, I will really appreciate it.

Comment: Can't really add anything here to this question, it is to broad in my opinion. But is it still a common believe that "good" MVVM avoids code behind at all cost? Code behind is a must in a lot of situations you can't avoid it, and you shouldn't. What you should do is split UI logic from Business logic and from Design, thats imho the whole reason of MVVM.

Comment: I updated my post, added that following MVVM pattern is probably not essential in this particular case. Let's no focus on MVVM, it's more about how to extend a control with a user-defined event.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the complete code because this was all very hard to develop and it's very much code (used in the software CCFinder), also it's not perfect, but it does it's job.

```
    <CCFinder:AnimatedScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="{Binding IsItemsFound, Converter={StaticResource __boolToVisibilityConverter}}" Margin="36,211,38,72" 
                  ScrollChanged="ScrollViewer_ScrollChanged" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Focusable="False" x:Name="ScrolView1">

            <ItemsControl Name="_itemsControl"  ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentImages}"
            ...
```

In the codebehind:

```
    private void ScrollViewer_ScrollChanged(object sender, ScrollChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.VerticalOffset + e.ViewportHeight == e.ExtentHeight)
        {
            var scroller = ((ScrollViewer)sender);
            scroller.ReleaseMouseCapture();
            scroller.InvalidateScrollInfo();
            ((OverviewViewModel)this.DataContext).ShowMoreTriggered();
        }
    }
```

So here comes the important part: in the ViewModel class I set the MaximumImages property to a higher value... it begins with about 50 and is then raised to 251 and then to 500 when this is triggered again. In the setter of the MaximumImages, the WPF framework is notified that CurrentImages has changed, and in the CurrentImages getter I have a lot of clunky code that realizes that the MaximumImages number is now higher than before, and adds new items to CurrentImages (all in the getter). Not too nice, but it works and is mostly in the ViewModel class:

```
    public void ShowMoreTriggered()
    {
        if (Photos != null && !ShowMoreTriggeredActive && MaximumImages < Photos.Count)
        {
            ShowMoreTriggeredActive = true;
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate
                                             {
                                                 Thread.Sleep(1000);
                                                 MaximumImages = MaximumImages < 251 ? 251 : 500;
                                                 Thread.Sleep(1500);
                                                 ShowMoreTriggeredActive = false;
                                             });
        }
    }

    private int _maximumImages;
    public int MaximumImages
    {
        get
        {
            return _maximumImages;
        }
        set
        {
            _maximumImages = value;
            InvokePropertyChanged("MaximumImages");
            InvokePropertyChanged("CurrentImages");
        }
    }
```

Of course it would be more elegant to raise a user-defined event in case the scroll event reaches the lowest point, but I guess it would only produce more code, and not less, because it would certainly would be propagated from the ScrollChanged event anyways.

Comment: Thank you and sorry for not responding so long. This is a good tip, however I will strive to find a more reusable solution so I can encapsulate this behavior by either defining a custom even (still need to figure out how to do it) or subclassing the control.

Comment: If you find a solution, I would be very happy to know this. :-)